# Fastest way to get occurrence of each element

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DataFrame looking like this

```
                                             name     Country   ... 
1                                            Paul     Germany
2                                            Paul     Germany
3                                          George     Italy
3                                          George     Italy   
3                                          George     Italy
                       ...
N                                            John     USA
```

I'm looking for the occurence of each element of the name column, such has

```
                                             name     Country   Count 
1                                            Paul     Germany    2000
2                                          George     Italy       500
                          ...
N                                            John     USA       40000
```

Any idea what is the most optimal way to do it ?

Because this is quite long

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['name'])['name'].transform(pd.Series.value_counts)
```

Comment: Why second row in second dataframe is George, Italy and not Paul, Germany as in the first?

Comment: I would also like to remove the duplicates, but it's not obligatory

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
df.groupby(['name', 'Country']).size()
```

example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'name' : ['paul', 'paul', 'George', 'George', 'George'],
    'Country': ['Germany', 'Italy','Germany','Italy','Italy']})

df
```

output:

```
    Country name
0   Germany paul
1   Italy   paul
2   Germany George
3   Italy   George
4   Italy   George
```

Group by and get count:

```
df.groupby(['name', 'Country']).size()
```

output:

```
name    Country
George  Germany    1
        Italy      2
paul    Germany    1
        Italy      1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to the counts with respect to the `name` column, you don't need to use `groupby`, you can just use select the `name` column from the DataFrame (which returns a `Series` object) and call `value_counts()` on it directly:

```
df['name'].value_counts()
```